# avoid data insertion when page is refreshed in coldfusion

Tags: image, coldfusion

I am new to Coldfusion.when I refresh the page data are inserted  twice,please a way to avoid data insertion when page is refreshed in coldfusion

Comment: short answer for a short question, cflocation to a different page.  expand your question with your code and how you're doing things.  this question is bait for down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a flag in the session indicating whether to insert data to database table. Do following the steps:

1. Before insertion, check whether the session value is `"Y"` or not
2. If session value is `"Y"`, insert the data and change session value to `"N"`
3. If session value is `"N"`, do not insert data into table.

If page is refreshed after insertion, it will check the session value and will find `"N"`.
So the data will not be inserted.

Comment: this answer meet to my requirement. its easy any effective solution.Thanx

Answer (score 3):

After you've ran the INSERT statement you'll want to use `<cflocation>` like Travis said

```
<cflocation url="yoururl" addtoken="false">
```

You'll want to add `addtoken="false"` to your `cflocation` because that will prevent passing in client variables through the url.

Answer (score 1):

Have your display page submit to a process page.  Once its done processing, redirect back to your display page.  in this way, the insert/update/delete is only started by pressing the Insert/Update/Delete button on your display page.

Answer (score 0):

Page refreshes are one of several possible ways that you could get duplicate records.  I think the most effective way to prevent this is at the database.  Write your insert query in such a way that is only adds records that are not already there.

There are a couple of ways to do this.  My personal favourite is this:

```
    INSERT INTO myTable ( field1, field2, etc )
    SELECT DISTINCT value1, value2, etc
    FROM   someSmallTable
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS
           (
              subquery to check for existing records
           )
```

This is a generic suggestion.  Some of the details can change depending on the database software being used.

Comment: This is a pretty poor implementation as it takes extra time to check for a record when we would already know the data was inserted. You can add url parameters to your cflocation if you want to give the end user a notification that it was added.

Comment: This is a good solution for a batch insert that you might get from importing an xls or something but it won't prevent other things that can change in the front end outside of the database, counters, conditions, etc that aren't effected by the db and should still be mitigated. Granted the OP asked about multiple inserts but looking at the broader picture this is only part of the answer.